# How to interact with Python routes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I'm building a python/flask app with jinja templates that will hold some html/javascript applications. This particular one uses jQuery to show different html/js code within the same browser window. The problem that I'm having is that the show() function doesn't seem to see the python route where I'm rendering the code I want it to access.

The python routes:

```
import os, datetime
from flask import Flask, current_app, Blueprint, render_template, abort, request, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask.ext.login import (current_user, login_required, login_user, logout_user, confirm_login, fresh_login_required)
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

import models
from libs.User import User
import random, string

leadership_app = Blueprint('leadership_app', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@leadership_app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')

@leadership_app.route("/leadership/washington/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def washington():

    return render_template('/leadership/Globe.html')

@leadership_app.route("/leadership/location/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def location():

    return render_template('/leadership/location.html')
```

Globe.html (which is wrapped in jinja):

```
if (locationClick == 0){
complete = ++complete
locationClick = ++locationClick
checkComplete(complete/4)
}
console.log(complete/4)
 $('#location').attr('src', '/leadership/location/');
 $("#location").show();
})
```

location.html is in templates>leadership

Edit:

Thanks to @Leandro Poblet I'm now using the $.get() function and it appears that I can see the route, but I can't seem to load location.html. I don't get any errors, but using developer tools in chrome I can see that the GET method is getting stuck on "pending" I've tried removing @login_required and making sure that all of the html files that I'm trying to $.show() have urls to load from so I know that there are no gaps there.

At this point I'm thinking that it may be that some .mp4 files I'm attempting to load are slowing everything down. They're not huge files (all under 100MB), so is there some way that I should be treating the video on the python end that will get them to load properly?

Here's the content of location.html:

```
<script src="/static/washington/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/washington/js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script>
var htmlContainer = d3.select("body")                                   

htmlContainer.append("img")
.attr('id','iimage1')
.attr('class','zoom')
   .attr("src","/static/washington/img/Overlays-02.png")

htmlContainer.append("img")
.attr('id','iimage2')
.attr('class','zoom')
   .attr("src","/static/washington/img/Overlays-03.png")

htmlContainer.append("img")
.attr('id','iimage3')
.attr('class','zoom')
   .attr("src","/static/washington/img/Overlays-04.png")

htmlContainer.append("img")
.attr('id','iimage4')
.attr('class','zoom')
   .attr("src","/static/washington/img/MapOverlay-01.png")

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
                                    .attr("height", window.innerHeight)
                                    .attr("id","pad")
                                    .attr("viewBox","0 0 2048 1536")    

svgContainer.append("image")
   .attr('width', 2048)
   .attr('height', 1536)
   .attr("xlink:href","/static/washington/img/LabledMap-01.png")

 svgContainer.append("image")
        .attr("id","complete")
        .attr('width', 141)
        .attr('height', 133)
        .attr("x",210)
        .attr("y",1370)
        .attr("xlink:href","/static/washington/img/backarrow-06.png")


  svgContainer.append("image")
        .attr("id","help")
        .attr('width', 141)
        .attr('height', 133)
        .attr("x",40)
        .attr("y",1370)
        .attr("xlink:href","/static/washington/img/info_button.png")

 svgContainer.append("rect")
    .attr('class',"help")
    .style("fill","red")
    .attr('width', 141)
        .attr('height', 133)
        .attr("x",40)
        .attr("y",1370)
    .attr("opacity",".01")  

svgContainer.append("circle")
        .attr("id","image1")
         .attr("cx",744)
         .attr("cy",408)
         .attr("r",123)
         .style("fill","white").style("opacity",".01")

svgContainer.append("circle")
        .attr("id","image2")
         .attr("cx",1044)
         .attr("cy",1164)
         .attr("r",123)
         .style("fill","white").style("opacity",".01")

svgContainer.append("circle")
        .attr("id","image3")
         .attr("cx",1139)
         .attr("cy",708)
          .attr("r",123)
         .style("fill","white").style("opacity",".01")




d3.xml("/static/washington/data/blank.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
   document.getElementById("pad").appendChild(xml.documentElement);
})  


$(document).ready(function() {



$("#complete").on("click touchstart",function(e){   e.preventDefault();
var ifr = parent.document.getElementById("location");
$(ifr).hide();
})

$(".zoom").on("click touchstart",function(e){   e.preventDefault();
$(this).fadeOut();
d3.select("#pad").transition().attr("viewBox","0 0 2048 1536")
})

$(".prompt").on("click touchstart",function(e){ e.preventDefault();
$(this).fadeOut();
d3.select("#pad").transition().attr("viewBox","0 0 2048 1536")
})

$(".zoom").hide();


$("#image1").on("click touchstart",function(e){ e.preventDefault();
//d3.select("#pad").transition().attr("viewBox","450 200 400 375")
$("#iimage1").delay('200').fadeIn()
})

$("#image2").on("click touchstart",function(e){ e.preventDefault();
//d3.select("#pad").transition().attr("viewBox","800 1000 400 375")
$("#iimage2").delay('200').fadeIn()
})

$("#image3").on("click touchstart",function(e){ e.preventDefault();
//d3.select("#pad").transition().attr("viewBox","900 550 400 375")
$("#iimage3").delay('200').fadeIn()
})

$(".help").on("click touchstart",function(e){   e.preventDefault();
$("#iimage4").delay('200').fadeIn()
})

})  



</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function to do that:

```
if (locationClick == 0){
complete = ++complete
locationClick = ++locationClick
checkComplete(complete/4)
}
console.log(complete/4)
$.get('/leadership/location/', function(data) {
$('#location').htm(data);
$("#location").show();
});
})
```

Also, in flask's blueprints you can avoid writing the same prefix over and over by adding **url_prefix** to your blueprint instance like this:

```
leadership_app = Blueprint('leadership_app', __name__, url_prefix='/leadership', template_folder='templates')
```

Comment: Hm. I'm actually getting a similar issue to the original one when I use your code. I don't get any error in the terminal, but when I use the developer tool I can see that the GET method is stuck on "pending." Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @Milazzo Do you mean the request gets stuck and does not show the data or error whatsoever?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And the only way I was able to figure out that much was through the developer tool in chrome.

Comment: Are you sure there's not something wrong with the view itself? Maybe the template's not loading or, if it has more code, something is taking a lot of time to execute. Did you check if the `@login_required` is not meddling with this?

Comment: Ok, I tried a few things and have some ideas about what might be going wrong. I'm going to add an edit to my initial question.

Comment: @Milazzo Could you also paste the content of location.html? Maybe there's something there that's causing the error and we can't seem to see through it.

Comment: There you go. Thanks.